# Is it possible to host single file asp.net core 5 blazor in iis?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, deployment, blazor-server-side

I want to host single file asp.net core 5 blazor - published with produce single file - with iis? When I do that , IIS in windows server 2016 returns status code 500 that indicates internal server error.

Comment: What do you mean publish single file on IIS? As far as I known, published blazor application is made up of multiples files. https://i.stack.imgur.com/6h1g1.png If you publish a single file, you need to make sure there's a handler mapping can handle this kind of file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single-file deployments are not supported in IIS, This is a known limitation of in-process hosting at least in .Net 5.

Please refer below thread for more info.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14473

Answer (score 0):

500 internal error is generic issue, you may check full error message on the server. Have you installed your .net 5 bundled on server? You may refer to this tutorial https://windowswebhostingreview.com/simple-way-to-host-your-asp-net-core-in-iis/